# TI sensortag cc2650 connection with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, sensor

I have problem with connection between Rasberry Pi 3 and TI sensortag CC2650.
As soon as I power on raspberry, sensortag shuts down, and I can not see him, either from raspberry or from mobile application ( TI application from google store). When I power off raspberry, I can connect to sensortag via phone and it sends good informations. 
When raspberry is powered on, and when I restart sensortag, I can see him for a couple of moments.

Gattol command :

```
 sudo gatttool -I -i hci0 -m 48 -b b2:b3:48:bc:6c:07
 [b2:b3:48:bc:6c:07][LE]> primary
 Command Failed: Disconnected
```

hciconfig up and dev :

```
  sudo hciconfig hci0 up
[b2:b3:48:bc:6c:07][LE]> connect
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)

  hciconfig dev
  hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
       BD Address: B8:27:EB:FB:A3:C4  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
       UP RUNNING
       RX bytes:1025 acl:0 sco:0 events:56 errors:0
       TX bytes:1578 acl:0 sco:0 commands:48 errors:0
```

I added 
`EnableLE = true 
AttributeServer = true`
lines to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf , but nothing changed.
Of course, when I add tisensortag deployment package to Kura, there isn't any info from sensor, either on the cloud or on console.

Answer (score 0):

You can not see the SensorTag because it is connected to your development board. When you power off the raspberry yo can not close correctly the link with the sensortag and as a result you can not connect once again to the  sensortag via your phone.

Open correctly the link, and in the end close the link.

If you want an application capable of working with all the sensors from CC2541DK, CC2650STK, ThunderBoard React and Sense (e.g. accelerometer, magnetometer, gyroscope, barometer, IR temperature  etc.), you can download it from: http://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9p054xsjjr1n – the software is able of giving new uses (movement & magnetic security, accelerometer mouse, PC remote control and wireless presenters) to all these IoT SensorTags. For more information: http://www.blesstags.eu. Thank you so much and have fun!